# Show Partial video in MediaElement

Tags: wpf, video, mediaelement

I want to use the media element, yet display only part of the video rectangle.

for example : if the video is 100X100 px, i would like to show only the left half of the video, e.g the 50x100 px on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in a `ContentPresenter` with negative [`Margins`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) and [`ClipToBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) set to `true`, this will crop the video.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting the Clip property of MediaElement. You can set it to any PathGeometry, below is a simple example.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="Window1" Height="378" Width="472"> 
    <Canvas> 
        <MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Play" Name="myME" Source="c:\\1.wmv" Width="320"  Height="240" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        </MediaElement>       
    </Canvas> 
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
using System; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Controls; 
using System.Windows.Input; 
using System.Windows.Media; 
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; 
using System.Windows.Shapes; 

namespace tests 
{ 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml 
    /// </summary> 
    public partial class Window1 : Window 
    { 
        public Window1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent();  
            this.MyMedia1.Clip = 
               new RectangleGeometry( new Rect(0, 0, myME.Width/3, myME.Height));  
        } 
    } 
}
```